# Runtime permissions are supposed to be in same method. How to handle it properly?

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

When I need to take permission for storage, I simply have a method, like this:

```
public boolean hasStoragePermission(Activity context, int requestCode){

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, requestCode);
            return false;
        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},requestCode);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Now I can call this function whenever I need:

```
if(hasStoragePermission(context, requestCode){
     //do the work
 }
```

But in case of location:

```
public boolean hasPermission(){
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And when I call it:

```
  public void read(final LocationSetter locationSetter) {
    if(!hasPermission()){return;}

    flpClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    flpClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            locationSetter.processLocation(location);
        }
    });
}
```

It says that `Call requires permission`. Why is that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Lint checks are powerful, but they are not magic. This Lint rule is looking for evidence that you have the code to check for runtime permissions, and it does not see it.

It is possible that you will have better luck if you replace the if-negative-then-return approach with an if-positive-do-work approach:

```
if (hasPermission()) {
  // TODO insert your fused location provider work here
}
```

Or, just suppress the Lint check for this particular method. There should be a quick-fix for that available from Android Studio. In the end, the Lint rule is there to help ensure that you do the right thing, and if you are certain that you are doing the right thing, you do not need that Lint rule in this case.